# How to perform pivoting for the below query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have

```
DispositionCode #OfAccounts %OfAccounts
Contact           2            7
NC                3           11
Paid              2            7
PTP               21           75
```

being generated by

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(DispositionCode Varchar(10),[#OfAccounts] INT,[%OfAccounts] INT)
Insert into @T Values('Contact',2,7),('NC',3,11),('Paid',2,7),('PTP',21,75)
Select *
From @T
```

Lookng for the below format

```
Vals         Contact    NC  Paid    PTP
#OfAccounts    2        3   2       21
%OfAccounts    7        11  7       75
```

Might be with Pivoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's both unpivot and pivot. Unpivoting is performed here using `cross apply` and pivoting using `pivot`.

```
select *
from (
    select DispositionCode, x.*
    from @T
    cross apply (
        values ('#OfAccounts', [#OfAccounts]), ('%OfAccounts', [%OfAccounts])
    ) x (vals, val)
) t pivot (
    max(val) for DispositionCode in ([Contact],[NC],[Paid],[PTP])
) pvt;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/SJOL38580)